# Converting substrings from an input file to a double value?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void getBaseCoord(string droneInfo, double& x, double& y, double& z){
   // x= stod(droneInfo.substr(31, 3));
    //y= stod(droneInfo.substr(34, 3));
   // z= stod(droneInfo.substr(37, 3));
    string strx, stry, strz;
    strx = droneInfo.substr(31, 3);
    stry = droneInfo.substr(34, 3);
    strz = droneInfo.substr(37,3);
    x = stof(strx);
    y = stof(stry);
    z = stof(strz);
```

The above is an excerpt from a project I'm working on currently for a novice c++ course. I am reading this string from an input file:

```
9673767892DroaninAlong4880021DO4.37.33.88.19.33.8U
```

The commented out part was an attempt to convert the substrings from the string line into a double value, for the purpose of the function operations. However, I am unable to convert these in this manner, and I get an error upon compilation, saying `stod` is not declared (I guess it thinks it's a variable?)

What is the proper way to convert substrings into double values within a function?

Comment: You must `#include <string>`. If you did not pull in the standard library via `using namespace std;` you must prefix the calls with `std::` like so: `std::stod(droneInfo.substr(31, 3));`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what stod() is, but it is highly suggestive of the [C library `strtod()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) which performs exactly that operation.

Note that the function takes two parameters, though the second one may be NULL.  The first parameter is a C-style string, so a conversion is probably needed:

```
void getBaseCoord(string droneInfo, double& x, double& y, double& z)
{
    x = strtod(droneInfo.substr(31, 3).cstr(), NULL);
    y = strtod(droneInfo.substr(34, 3).cstr(), NULL);
    z = strtod(droneInfo.substr(37, 3).cstr(), NULL);
}
```

Comment: `std::stod` is the `c++11` function for converting a string to a double. There's also `stof`, `stold`, `stoi`, `stol`,`stoul`, `stoull`, and `stoull` for `float`, `long double`, `integer`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, and `unsigned long long` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `stringstream` class. You would use it like this:

```
std::string strx = droneInfo.substr(31, 3);
double x;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << strx;
ss >> x;
```

Remember to add `#include <sstream>` for this solution to work and to `.clear()` your stringstream object if you are going to reuse it. You can see a full example [here](http://ideone.com/L1ztOU).